# Release community, A site with those parameters is already in use

Tags: ant, change-set, partner-communities

We have created a community in a sandbox and would like to release it using ANT or Change sets. But we are now getting an error: A site with those parameters is already in use.

I realize now that we have created a community in production with the same name, to register the URL, we didn't realize it would become a problem.

How can we push our changes from our Sandbox to Production? We want to delete or override the current community since it is an empty and unconfigured environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting a community is not possible, we have solved the issue by refreshing the sandbox and manually re-setup the community in the sandbox. Now it is possible to release the changes using ant.